# How to handle no connection for PhoneGap Android App Natively

Tags: android, html, cordova, android-webview

Based upon the documention for the [PhoneGap Connection API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_connection_connection.md.html#connection.type) it would appear that failed connections to the internet are handled in HTML5 to show a simple alert box using the browser. How can I delegate errors from within Android natively.

If there's no connection, I want to display my native loading screen (splash), and then display a simple dialogue box in android natively
. Currently I'm creating my webview using phoneGap with the code below...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // if (phoneGap.connection != false)
    //      initiate loadURL
    // else
    //      load up a different activity and show dialogue box...

    super.loadUrl("http://classtempo.org/teacher.html");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I add this line before super.loadUrl():

```
super.setStringProperty("errorUrl", "file:///android_asset/www/no_connection.html");
```